# How does $PA + \neg Con(PA)$ prove its Gödel sentence?

Tags: first-order-logic

It is my understanding that for a theory not to prove the negation of its Gödel sentence $G$ the theory has to be $\omega$-consistent. I have seen the definition of $\omega$-consistency, though I still can't quite get why it is required.
For instance, the informal argument for the undecidability of $G$ goes like: "Assume $T$ is consistent. Suppose $T$ proves $G$. Then let $k$ be the Gödel number of this proof. Then $T \vdash Pk\sharp G$ and so $T$ proves $\exists x Px\sharp G = \neg G$ and $T$ is inconsistent. Now suppose $T \vdash \neg G$. * Then for some $k$, $k$ is the Gödel number of a proof of $G$, thus $T \vdash G$ and $T$ is inconsistent."

Now, I imagine the mistake is in the part marked by the asterisk, as in an $\omega$-inconsistent theory we can prove $\exists x \phi(x)$ without ever proving $\phi(k)$ for some $k$. But I still can't seem to make it click. Foregoing that part of the argument we just have that it is not necessary that the theory not prove $\neg G$, but how can we be sure that it does prove?
Particularly, how does $PA + \neg Con(PA)$ prove $\neg G$, for instance? I can see how it would prove e.g. "there is a proof of a contradiction from $PA$" despite for all $k$ proving "$k$ is not a proof of a contradiction from $PA$", as the former is an axiom, but I can't picture what a deduction of $\neg G$ would be like. If anyone can show me, I think that would help. Or even help me in a different way if showing one explicitly is not possible (nonstandard length?).

I have searched and found another question here on SE on the same thing, by the way. Though the answers there didn't do it for me, unfortunately. I wasn't sure of the etiquette - e.g. should I revive that question? (Some communities frown upon this) - so I decided to post a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*By the Godel sentence, I assume you mean the $G$ which basically says, "I am not provable in $PA$."*

Let $T=PA+\neg Con(PA)$. Remember the following basic fact of first-order logic: an inconsistent theory proves everything.

The crucial fact is that the fact above is *provable in $PA$*! Specifically, $PA$ proves "If I am inconsistent, then I prove $\varphi$" for every sentence $\varphi$. This is because $PA$ is strong enough to reason about basic manipulations of proofs, so e.g. $PA$ is strong enough to reason as follows:

> Given an arbitrary sentence $\varphi$ and a proof $S$ of $\psi\wedge\neg\psi$, I can form a proof via contradiction of $\varphi$: assume $\neg\varphi$, copy $S$, and deduce $\varphi$.

(If you really want to get nitty-gritty, you can actually cook up a computable function $f$ such that $PA$ proves that if $k$ is the Godel number of a sentence, and $m$ is the Godel number of a $PA$-proof of $0=1$, then $f(k, m)$ is the Godel number of a proof of the sentence with Godel number $k$.)

Now, $G$ happens to be a sentence in the language of $PA$; so - according to $PA$ - if $PA$ is inconsistent, then $PA$ proves $G$.

Well, $T$ proves that $PA$ is inconsistent, and $T$ proves that if $PA$ is inconsistent then $PA$ proves $G$ (since $T$ contains $PA$), so $T$ proves "$PA$ proves $G$." But this is exactly $\neg G$!

Comment: Hum. So, $T$ proves both $\neg G_{PA}$ and $G_{PA}$, solely because $T$ "works under the assumption" that $PA$ is inconsistent (thus proves everything). Correct? I can see how this happens. In any case, my question concerned the Gödel sentence of $T$ itself. How does an $\omega$-inconsistent $T$ react to $G_{T}$? It proves its negation, doesn't it?

Comment: @wet No, that's not accurate. For every sentence $\varphi$, $T$ proves "$PA$ proves $\varphi$." However, just because $T$ proves that $PA$ proves something, doesn't mean $PA$ proves that thing! In the case of $\neg G_{PA}$, though, $\neg G_{PA}$ *is exactly* the statement "$PA$ proves $G_{PA}$" - so since $T$ proves "$PA$ proves $G_{PA}$," this means $T$ proves $\neg G_{PA}$.

Comment: Roughly speaking, you're trying to go from "$T\vdash$"$PA\vdash\varphi$"" to "$T\vdash\varphi$". But this doesn't work in general. For the *specific* sentence $\neg G_{PA}$, though, it does - because "$\neg G_{PA}$" just asserts the $PA$-provability of something. In fact, $T$ will *not* prove $G_{PA}$ (assuming $PA$ is consistent)!

Comment: Alright, I think I get it now: recapitulating, according to $T$, for all $x$, $PA \vdash x$ - say, by modus ponens on "$\neg Con(PA) \to \forall x PA \vdash x$" (provable from $PA$ alone) and "$\neg Con(PA)$" (axiom of $T$). Thus $T$ proves "$PA \vdash G_{PA}$", which is $\neg G_{PA}$. OK. But here's my question: leaving $PA$ and $T$ aside, I was under the impression that an $\omega$-inconsistent theory would prove the negation of its own Gödel sentence. Is this not the case? Thanks for taking the time, BTW!

Comment: @wet Well, first of all it is true that $T\vdash \neg G_T$. Why? Well, $T$ proves that $T$ is inconsistent, since $T$ thinks $PA$ is inconsistent and $T$ knows that no theory containing an inconsistent theory is consistent. So $T$ proves "$T$ proves $G_T$," and "$T$ proves $G_T$" is exactly "$\neg G_T$." That said, it is *not* the case in general that an $\omega$-inconsistent theory need prove the negation of its own Godel sentence. The reason is that $\omega$-consistency is too strong a condition - it could fail in a lot of ways, not necessarily just via thinking itself inconsistent.

Comment: The only theories that prove the negation of their own Godel sentence are the theories which fail to be $\omega$-consistent *in a precise way*. But we can have a $\Sigma_1$-correct theory which is $\omega$-inconsistent; such a theory will not think its own Godel sentence is decidable, but will still fail to be $\omega$-inconsistent.

Comment: Ohh I didn't know $T$ proved it was inconsistent. That seems to be crucial. So, $T$ proves "$T$ proves $G_{T}$", - similarly to how it proves "$PA$ proves $G_{PA}$" -, but $T$ does not actually prove $G_{T}$, is that correct? On the second part: so I guess I misunderstood something earlier (as in, before even making the question). For some reason I had the impression that an $\omega$-inconsistent theory always proved its $\neg G$. What then is the motivation behind Rosser's trick?

Comment: @wet Re: your first point, yes, exactly. Re: Rosser, the motivation behind Rosser's trick is still to get rid of the need to assume $\omega$-consistency: Rosser wanted to do away with the assumption of $\omega$-consistency, and since $\omega$-inconsistent theories *might* prove their own Godel sentences, he needed a new sentence.

Comment: Alright, I think that'll do it - I have plenty to digest now! Thanks.